# Why isn't the map fragment shown?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

So I'm trying to do a simple Application with a Google Maps Fragment in it. I started from a preset out of Android-Studio. Since newly, the toolbar is shown but not the map fragment. Following, you will see my code and the Stack Trace:

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="1080dp"
    android:layout_height="1920dp"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1720dp"
        tools:context="com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity"
        />



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testingmapingmarker23;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;



import static com.example.testingmapingmarker23.R.id.map;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        final Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    }





}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testingmapingmarker23">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value=" AIz...." />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000023/n/armeabi-v7a
07-05 23:22:08.294 21301-21845/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000023/n/armeabi
07-05 23:22:08.296 21301-21849/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES:4548>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
07-05 23:22:08.298 21301-21849/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES:4548>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
07-05 23:22:08.298 21301-21849/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 E/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-21301-0] bindTextureImage: error binding external image: 0x501
07-05 23:22:08.343 21301-21849/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES:4548>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
07-05 23:22:08.345 21301-21849/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES:4548>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

And this repeats over and over. I'm using a OnePlus One with Android 6.0.1 and shown API 23. The App runs, but it doesn't show the map fragment.

Comment: `android:layout_height="1720dp"` looks odd

Comment: this is because the map shouldn't be the whole screen. There should be a place for the toolbar, too.

Comment: Then use a LinearLayout... There is no reason to hard-code the size of an element

Comment: I changed it but the error stays the same

Comment: Does it show, or is it blank? If blank, then the API key is the problem, usually. Otherwise, you also have `android:layout_height="1920dp"` at the top

Comment: It is a blank app where you can only see the toolbar on top. The layout_height - shall I remove this or is this positive?

Comment: @cricket_007 I deleted the layout_height an it worked! Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For Layout:

If you are using your custom **Toolbar**, better change your ***style*** to
***NoActionBar***.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Using relative layout,
 for toolbar, keep

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and for that map fragment

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This will simply place  your toolbar at the top and below part as map fragment.

Now for the Map not showing:

Have you put the **Google Play Services** dependency in your app??

Also add this to your manifest file just above your permissions.

```
 <permission
        android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Sorry, I couldn't comment so posted an answer.

Hope it helps !!